# How to mock a method inside another module during unit testing

Tags: django, python-3.x, mocking, python-mock, django-unittest

In one of my test case the flow requires that a customer provision process wherein the call goes to the api.py file where in the response is saved from the function create_t_customer like following:

In api.py file it is using the method create_t_customer imported from file customer.py

```
response = create_t_customer(**data)
```

In customer.py file the code for function is

```
def create_t_customer(**kwargs):
    t_customer_response = Customer().create(**kwargs)
    return t_customer_response
```

I want to mock the function create_t_customer inside the unittest.
Current I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working

```
class CustomerTest(APITestCase):
    @mock.patch("apps.dine.customer.create_t_customer")
    def setUp(self,mock_customer_id):
        mock_customer_id.return_value = {"customer":1}
```

But this is not able to mock the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should mock it inside the file it is imported. For example you have declared `create_t_customer` in `customer.py` and using it in `api.py`. You should mock it from `api` instead of `customer` module like this.

```
class CustomerTest(APITestCase):
    @mock.patch("x.y.api.create_t_customer")
    def test_xyz(self, mock_customer_id):
        mock_customer_id.return_value = {"customer":1}
```

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to explain your decision? 
Or where you can read about this in the documentation or somewhere else..